# How to express "accommodatable"?

Tags: word-choice

Is there some word or phrase which gets the idea of "able to be accommodated" across without using the (apparently nonexistent) word "accommodatable"?

I am going for the idea of "able to be made to happen."

Comment: There's a good-sized family of words which could suit (feasible, viable, tenable, reasonable, doable, practical or practicable, etc), but I imagine what you find lacking is the sense of *service*, as in "not only is that possible, but sure, *I could do that for you*"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adjective is [accommodable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Accommodable); just ignore the capital.

Comment: +1 Even though on it's own it sounds like a portable toilet.

Comment: Wellp. That settles it. Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

Plain, direct language serves better than words that may be less common:

- We can accommodate your needs.
- We can meet your needs.
- We can do what you need.
- Your needs can be accommodated
- Your needs can be met.
- We can do what you need.

Comment: Yes, accommodate is one of those 'fancy' words that people use to make themselves sounds smarter (like 'apprehend the suspect' instead of 'catch', etc.).  Accommodate is even worse since it doesn't have any strong sense by itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think [realisable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Realisable) may express you concept:

> - capable of existing or taking place or proving true; possible to do,
>     accomplishable, achievable, doable, manageable,
>     possible.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what meaning of accommodated you're looking for. My initial thought was to go with *satiable* or *appeasable*.

Going with another sense, *habitable* could work.

---

In accordance with your edit, *able to be accommodated* vs *able to be made happen* have a very, very slight overlap. In that case, I would have to go with plain ol' *possible*.

Answer (score 1):

Needs can be **[satisfied](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/satisfy)** in the sense that they can be put to an end (accommodated). They can also be satisfied in the sense that they are fulfilled or met.

If needs can be satisfied, then they are **satisfiable**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stressing service, as in "Your special needs can be accommodated," I would go with a sentence like that, rather than stating such needs, people, etc. are accommodable.